# Android: Gallery view, can we name the images?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-imageview

When we display the images in a Gallery view in Android, is their any way to set a title or set image name for the gallery items?

Technically I would like to name each and every gallery item. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, with two solutions.

You can has these components for titles (Such a TextView) and update its value in the setOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected method, that was called when you are flinging your itens around with the new object that will be in the center.

In this case: lets say you have an LinearLayout with an TextView with id: "title" and below it an Gallery with id: "itens".

You should have a method like this:

```
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.itens);

    coverflow.setAdapter(yourSimpleAdapterWithYourData);

    coverflow.setCallbackDuringFling(true);
    coverflow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            MyObject book = myData.get(arg2);
            title.setText(book.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

OR

You can write your own adapter and inflate a layout witch you can set the title there.

Comment: Can you please explain the first option. I would like to avoid the inflating a new layout and instead use the native gallery view activity of android.

Comment: I was looking for updating text in the gallery view itself, but I guess this is fine.